# PyQt: QStyledItemDelegate in QTableView on Windows Vista/7?

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyqt, qtableview

I would like to get a cell/row to look like this in a `QTableView`:

[image]

When running Ubuntu, the `QStyledItemDelegate` works for both the `QTreeView` and the `QTableView`, but on Windows, it only works on `QTreeView`, and only if I don't reimplement the `paint` method.

So my 2 questions are:

How do I get the `QStyledItemDelegate` to look like the above image in a `QTableView`?

How do I get the `QStyledItemDelegate` to look like the above image when reimplementing `paint`?

The image beside the text is **not** neccessary. I am just looking for the styled hover and selection box.
Just in case this is needed, my Qt version is 4.7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured enough of it out.

What I did not solve is why not overriding `QStyledItemDelegate.paint()` has a different effect from overriding it like:

```
def paint(self, painter, option, index):
    QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
```

but that was not part of my question anyway.

---

What I did solve is how to get the native appearance when painting manually. Previously, when painting the item, I used:

```
QApplication.style().drawControl(QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, option, painter)
```

which had the issue of not painting the native focus or selection. I had a look at the method signature of `QApplication.style().drawControl()`:

```
void QStyle::drawControl ( ControlElement element, const QStyleOption * option,
                           QPainter * painter, const QWidget * widget = 0 )
```

and noticed the `widget` parameter, and tried passing in a `QTreeView`. It worked. It does not matter what `QTreeView` is passed, but it makes the view render natively.

So in the end, rendering a native `QTableView` is as simple as calling:

```
QApplication.style().drawControl(QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, option, painter, QTreeView())
```

in the `QStyledItemDelegate`'s paint method.

Answer (score 1):

I've opened a thread on [qtcentre](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/47932-How-to-apply-TreeView-look-amp-feel-to-a-delegate?p=216093#post216093) asking for the same thing. The guy who answer me, provide me with a code example written in C++ and a picture showing the result. It seems to work fine in C++ but not in PySide (dont know about pyQt), so it may be a bug.

This is the working code:

```
void ProgressBarDelegate::paint( QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index ) const
{
QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);

if( index.column() == 1 )
{
int progress = index.data().toInt();

QStyleOptionProgressBar progressBarOption;
progressBarOption.rect = option.rect;
progressBarOption.rect.setTop( option.rect.top() + 1 );
progressBarOption.rect.setHeight( option.rect.height() - 2 );
progressBarOption.minimum = 0;
progressBarOption.maximum = 100;
progressBarOption.progress = progress;
progressBarOption.text = QString::number(progress) + "%";
progressBarOption.textVisible = true;
progressBarOption.textAlignment = Qt::AlignCenter;

QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ProgressBar, &progressBarOption, painter);
}
}
```